# Laravel multi-servers memcached session

Tags: laravel, session, memcached

I want to make Laravel use all memcached servers listed in config file to store session, because it can only use one server now.

Also every session must be setted to all servers and getted even if one of servers is down.

I know that the session system wraps the cache system, but still i dont know where to start.

Comment: You want to duplicate session data to multiple memcached servers in a cluster? Why are your memcached servers crashing often enough to make this a concern?

Comment: Well, i think it is more like precautionary measure from losing session data and it is interesting why we can use 2 and more servers for caching but not for storing session.

Comment: I don't think the caching system in Laravel duplicates values among multiple servers. See my answer below.

Comment: @Seteline When you use multiple servers for caching, that's for load balancing. The cached items only exist once, they're ust spread around.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the `php-memcached` client there is no way of doing this. When you configure this client with multiple servers it hashes the key to determine which server the value (in your case the session) will be sent to. There are some clients that allow replication by sending the value to multiple servers but this is not a common feature.

If you use long lived sessions or want to make sure they do not get deleted you should not use memcached (any cache for that matter) to store sessions. Even if you could use multiple servers a session might get evicted by the LRU algorithm when the cache is full. Use a permanent storage such as a file or a database in that case.

Comment: You could *conceivably* write your own session driver that simultaneously writes to every server in a list... but it'd be kinda silly.